# Compose Predefined Message in GroupMe from iOS app

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, groupme

I want to make an option in my app to open GroupMe app with a message ready to send to whomever I pick. I managed to do it with WhatsApp like this:

```
let scheme = "whatsapp://send?text=hello"
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL.init(string: scheme)!)
```

in GroupMe i tried -

```
let scheme = "groupme://compose?text=hello"
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL.init(string: scheme)!)
```

but it only opens the app without the option to send my message.

If it is not possible, another option that is ok for me is to open the message composer with a link attached instead of a message.

If none or possible, another option that I can handle with is opening GroupMe on the page with the list of groups.. right now it opens on the last page that was open in GroupMe.

any help with one of the three options will be appreciated.